# Setting dygraphs initial column visibility by series name

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I'm trying to set the initial visiblity of some dygraphs data series by column name.

This is because the data comes from a CSV file with columns that may come or go, but I know that a couple of the columns I want to be disabled by default - but I don't know what column number they may be (just the name).

I'm new to javascript, so the answer is likely simple.
I'm trying to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    g = new Dygraph(
        document.getElementById("graphdiv"),  // containing div
        "last/test.csv",
        {
            connectSeparatedPoints: true,
            includeZero: true
        }
    );

    g.setVisibility(g.indexFromSetName("writer_write_start") - 1, 0);
</script>
```

But this gives me an error. If I run the setVisibility command from the javascript console or an onclick event, it works fine. I suspect it's something to do with the Dygraph not being fully loaded by the time I try to run methods referring to data in the CSV file, and I need to run this in some other way after the dygraph has fully loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `new Dygraph` with the path to a CSV file as its data parameter, the call is asynchronous. So your suspicion is correct -- when you call `g.indexFromSetName("writer_write_start")`, the data needed to get the answer you want isn't available yet.

The best way to deal with this is by moving your setVisibility code into an initial `drawCallback`, like so:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    g = new Dygraph(
        document.getElementById("graphdiv"),  // containing div
        "last/test.csv",
        {
            connectSeparatedPoints: true,
            includeZero: true,
            drawCallback: function(dg, is_initial) {
                if (!is_initial) return;
                dg.setVisibility(dg.indexFromSetName("writer_write_start") - 1, 0);
            }
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I worked around it with a timer, but it's not completely reliable. This looks much better.