# Dygraphs setVisibility of column

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I'm trying to change the visibility of columns of Dygraph GVizChart.

This works:

```
function drawChart() {
  data = getData();
  window.chart1 = new Dygraph.GVizChart(
       document.getElementById('dygraphs')).draw(data, {
    });
  }
```

Also this works:

```
function drawChart() {
  data = getData();
  window.chart1 = new Dygraph.GVizChart(
       document.getElementById('dygraphs')).draw(data, {
            visibility: [false, true, true, true]
    });
  }
```

But inside `drawChart`, after that code, when I add following lines,

```
function drawChart() {
  data = getData();
  window.chart1 = new Dygraph.GVizChart(
       document.getElementById('dygraphs')).draw(data, {
    });
    window.chart1.setVisibility(0, true);
    window.chart1.setVisibility(1, false);
  }
```

I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setVisibility' of undefined. drawChart

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409513/setting-dygraphs-initial-column-visibility-by-series-name?rq=1), I thought maybe `chart1` is not ready at the time of execution. So I added this function:

```
    function showChange() {
        alert('show chart1:' + window.chart1);
        window.chart1.setVisibility(3, false);
    }
   
  <a href="#" onclick='showChange();return false;'>showChange</a>
```

But when I click `showChange` link, I get same error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setVisibility' of undefined

And alert window says:

> show chart1: undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Dygraph.GVizChart()` returns an object. `.draw()` does not.

You want something more like:

```js
window.chart1 = new Dygraph.GVizChart(document.getElementById('dygraphs'));
window.chart1.draw(data, {});
```

You're also going to run into problems because the dygraphs GViz wrapper does not have a `setVisibility()` method. You'll need to do get at the underlying Dygraph object for your code to work:

```js
function showChange() {
    alert('show chart1:' + window.chart1);
    window.chart1.date_graph.setVisibility(3, false);
}
```